# Setting up a DevStack node with Opendaylight backend

Tags: openstack, opendaylight, devstack

I am attempting to setup a DevStack node with a ODL networking backend.

I am using pike for Devstack. For ODL i am using Opendaylight Beryllium.

Devstack node has a public IP : 130.127.133.113
ODL installed node has a public IP : 130.127.133.175

I am using the following local.conf configuration.

```
    [[local|localrc]]
    HOST_IP=130.127.133.113
    SERVICE_HOST=130.127.133.113
    RABBIT_HOST=130.127.133.113
    DATABASE_HOST=130.127.133.113
    Q_HOST=130.127.133.113

    ADMIN_PASSWORD=nova
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
    RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
    SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
    SERVICE_TOKEN=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

    DATABASE_TYPE=mysql

    # Log
    USE_SCREEN=True
    SCREEN_LOGDIR=/opt/stack/logs/screen
    LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/xstack.sh.log
    LOGDAYS=1
    # Force config drive
    FORCE_CONFIG_DRIVE=True

    # Networks
    Q_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPE=vxlan
    Q_ML2_PLUGIN_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=opendaylight
    Q_ML2_PLUGIN_TYPE_DRIVERS=flat,vlan,vxlan
    ML2_L3_PLUGIN=odl-router
    NEUTRON_CREATE_INITIAL_NETWORKS=False
    enable_plugin networking-odl https://github.com/openstack/networking-odl stable/pike
    ODL_MODE=externalodl

    ODL_ENDPOINT=http://130.127.133.175:8080/controller/nb/v2/neutron
    ODL_USERNAME=admin
    ODL_PASSWORD=admin
    ODL_PROVIDER_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex

    # Services
    ENABLED_SERVICES=key,nova,n-api,n-cond,n-sch,n-novnc,n-cauth,placement-api,g-api,g-reg,q-svc,horizon,rabbit,mysql

    # Branches
    GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/pike
    HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/pike
    KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/pike
    NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/pike
    NOVA_BRANCH=stable/pike
```

I managed to build the DevStack successfully. Yet I am unable to create networks or provision VMs.

Kindly let me know weather the local.conf configuration is correct.

Any help is highly appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the problem is without logs and/or error messages. We
do run devstack successfully in upstream ODL integration/test jobs. Here is
the [local.conf for a compute node](https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/netvirt-csit-1node-0cmb-1ctl-2cmp-openstack-queens-upstream-stateful-itm-direct-tunnels-neon/334/compute_2/local.conf), and [one for a control node](https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/netvirt-csit-1node-0cmb-1ctl-2cmp-openstack-queens-upstream-stateful-itm-direct-tunnels-neon/334/control_1/local.conf). maybe that can
help?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check as you mentioned and get back to you soon.